# windows phone GPS tutorial showing wrong location

Tags: c#, gps, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-emulator, windows-mobile-gps

I had made an app for getting latitude and longitude and converting it into address I tried on emulator its showing *lat-47.669* and *long= -122.124*. I tested on device its showing location in japan. But, I am in Hyderabad,India. How can this be, please check whether my code is incorrect or its a device problem

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;
using System.Device.Location;
using PhoneApp3.GeocodeService;
using Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Services;
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;
namespace PhoneApp3
{
    public partial class map : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This variable is used to get the location
        /// from the windows phone location service
        /// </summary>
        GeoCoordinateWatcher myLocationWatcher;
        private GeoCoordinate MyCoordinate = null;
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for the PhoneApplicationPage object
        /// </summary>
        public map()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private ProgressIndicator ProgressIndicator = null;

        // My current location

        // Reverse geocode query
        private ReverseGeocodeQuery MyReverseGeocodeQuery = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Accuracy of my current location in meters;
        /// </summary>
        private double accuracy = 0.0;
        Double latitude, longitude;

        /// <summary>
        /// Click event handler for the high accuracy button
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void GetLocation(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Start data acquisition from the Location Service, high accuracy
            //accuracy can be one default and another high
            StartLocationService(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper method to start up the location data acquisition
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="accuracy">The accuracy level </param>
        private void StartLocationService(GeoPositionAccuracy accuracy)
        {
            // Reinitialize the GeoCoordinateWatcher
            myLocationWatcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(accuracy);
            myLocationWatcher.MovementThreshold = 20;

            // Add event handlers for StatusChanged and PositionChanged events
            myLocationWatcher.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(watcher_StatusChanged);
            myLocationWatcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);

            // Start data acquisition
            myLocationWatcher.Start();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handler for the StatusChanged event. This invokes MyStatusChanged on the UI thread and
        /// passes the GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        void watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //the dispatcher dispatches to the specified method when a status change occurs
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MyStatusChanged(e));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Custom method called from the StatusChanged event handler
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        void MyStatusChanged(GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Status)
            {
                case GeoPositionStatus.Disabled:
                    // The location service is disabled or unsupported.
                    // Alert the user
                    MessageBox.Show("location is unsupported on this device");
                    break;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handler for the PositionChanged event. This invokes MyStatusChanged on the UI thread and
        /// passes the GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
        {
            //Dispatcher invokes the event for position change.
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MyPositionChanged(e));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Custom method called from the PositionChanged event handler
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        void MyPositionChanged(GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
        {
            // Update the TextBlocks to show the current location
            LatitudeTextBlock.Text = e.Position.Location.Latitude.ToString("0.000");
            LongitudeTextBlock.Text += e.Position.Location.Longitude.ToString("0.000");
        }
        // for converting latitude longitude to address

        public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GetCurrentCoordinate();
        }

        private async void GetCurrentCoordinate()
        {
            Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
            geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;

            try
            {
                Geoposition currentPosition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                accuracy = currentPosition.Coordinate.Accuracy;
                latitude = Convert.ToDouble(LatitudeTextBlock.Text);
                longitude = Convert.ToDouble(LongitudeTextBlock.Text);
                MyCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(latitude, longitude);

                if (MyReverseGeocodeQuery == null || !MyReverseGeocodeQuery.IsBusy)
                {
                    MyReverseGeocodeQuery = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
                    MyReverseGeocodeQuery.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(MyCoordinate.Latitude, MyCoordinate.Latitude);
                    //  LongitudeTextBlock.Text = MyCoordinate.Longitude.ToString();
                    //  LatitudeTextBlock.Text = MyCoordinate.Latitude.ToString();
                    MyReverseGeocodeQuery.QueryCompleted += ReverseGeocodeQuery_QueryCompleted;
                    MyReverseGeocodeQuery.QueryAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // ...
                LatitudeTextBlock.Text = "hiiii";
            }
        }

        public void ReverseGeocodeQuery_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<IList<MapLocation>> e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                if (e.Result.Count > 0)
                {
                    MapAddress address = e.Result[0].Information.Address;
                    labelResults.Text = "Current Location: " + address.City + ", " + address.State;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you expect the software emulation of a hardware device to know your actual GPS location?

Comment: sorry @paddy i can't understand what you are saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LongitudeTextBlock.Text += e.Position.Location.Longitude.ToString("0.000");
```

Try using the above code